# How to find RBG or HEX code of a picture area?

Tags: 14.04

Suppose I have an image region with a particular color. Is there a software to find its color code instead of manualy 'eye-guessing'?

Comment: If you can take a screenshot, try this site: http://html-color-codes.info/colors-from-image/

Answer (score 2):

There a several color pickers that allow selecting colors from the screen:

- [gcolor2](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gcolor2) [image: Install gcolor2]

  > Gcolor2 is a GTK2 color selector to provide a quick and easy way to find colors for whatever task is at hand.<sup>[Project home](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcolor2/)</sup>
- [gpick](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpick) [image: Install gpick]

  > Select colors to create and export palettes in various formats.<sup>[Project home](http://code.google.com/p/gpick/)</sup>
- [grabc](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/grabc) [image: Install grabc] (Command line)

  > When this program is run, the mouse pointer is grabbed and changed to a cross  hair  and  when  the  mouse is clicked, the color of the clicked pixel is written to stdout in hex prefixed with #. It will the R, G,  B component also in the stderr.<sup>[Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/grabc)</sup>

Comment: Under Ubuntu 20.04, just installed grabc doesn't work and always return the same color